# Get sub category of current category in magento2

Tags: magento2, category

I want to create custom list (category) page in magento2.

**If current category has sub category then it's show sub category.**

**If current category have sub category and products then it's show both.**

**If current category has only products then it's show products only.**

which file I need to do changes?

Can anyone give me a suggestion?

Comment: what you have done so far ?

Comment: @Arunendra I didn't get any code for my problem otherwise I could try it.

Comment: where are u want to add this code ?

Comment: @AmitBera I want to add this code on app/design/frontend/<theme_vendoe>/<theme>/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**You can get sub-category by below code at list.phtml**

```
if($this->getLayer()->getCurrentCategory()):
$subcategories=$this->getLayer()->getCurrentCategory()->getCategories($this->getLayer()->getCurrentCategory()->getId());
    /* count and check the category have any sub category */
    if($subcategories->count()>0){

        foreach($subcategories as $subcategory){
            //echo "<pre>";
            //print_r($subcategory->getData());
            echo $subcategory->getName();
        }

    }else{
        // category does not have any sub category
    }
else:
        // category does not have any sub category

endif;
```

### Edit:

**add this code:**

```
<!-- add by amit bera -->
    <?php if($this->getLayer()->getCurrentCategory()):   ?>
        <?php 
        if($subcategories->count()>0){

            foreach($subcategories as $subcategory){
                //echo "<pre>";
                //print_r($subcategory->getData());
                echo $subcategory->getName();
            }

        }   
        ?>
    <?php endif ?>
```

just after `<?php if (!$_productCollection->count()): ?>`

and

**add below code:**

```
<!-- add by amit bera -->
    <?php if($this->getLayer()->getCurrentCategory()):   ?>
        <?php 
        if($subcategories->count()>0){

            foreach($subcategories as $subcategory){
                //echo "<pre>";
                //print_r($subcategory->getData());
                echo $subcategory->getName();
            }

        }   
        ?>
    <?php endif ?>
```

just after `<?php $pos = $block->getPositioned();
    ?>`

Get source code at http://codepad.org/VwvnFZge

Comment: let me check and I will tell you is it working or not?

Comment: it's working perfect!!!

Comment: now if current category has subcategory and product both then how can I get both?and current category don't have subcategory but only product then how get product only?

Comment: At list.phtml ,products are displayed default. check it have a default logic ,pleaase check that `<?php if (!$_productCollection->count()): ?>
    <div class="message info empty"><div><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('We can\'t find products matching the selection.') ?></div></div>
<?php else: ?>.... <?php endif; ?>`

Comment: So ,you need to merge my logic & existing logic at here ....If you want to show subcategory-Ue products at category page then please make Achor=yes

Comment: have u understood my point?

Comment: yes I understand but If I set Anchor=yes then subcategory will show in left side and I don't want there.I want subcategory and products both in grid if current category have both otherwise subcategory only or products only. your above code is perfect for getting subcategory now I want to change your above code and want to set condition that current category have subcategory and products both or only subcategory or only products and whatever condition is true as per that I need result in grid.

Comment: Please  share code of list.phtml. Are u want to show subcategory at list.phtml section or els?

Comment: yes I want to show subcategory on list.phtml page .it's default magento2's list.phtml file on this path **vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\frontend\templates\product**.

Comment: if you don't have magento2 in your PC let me know I will put list.phtml code here.

Answer (score 3):

**Get subcategory of current category**

```
<?php
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$category = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_category');//get current category
$subcats = $category->getChildrenCategories();
$_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
?>
<ul class="sub-cat">
    <?php
    foreach ($subcats as $subcat) {
            $_category = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($subcat->getId());
            $_outputhelper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
            $subcaturl = $subcat->getUrl();            
            $_imgHtml = '';
            if ($_imgUrl = $_category->getImageUrl()) {
                $_imgHtml = '<img src="' . $_imgUrl . '" />';
                $_imgHtml = $_outputhelper->categoryAttribute($_category, $_imgHtml, 'image');
                /* @escapeNotVerified */
                echo '<li><a href="' . $subcaturl . '" title="' . $subcat->getName() . '">' . $_imgHtml . '</a></li>';
            }

    } ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have created an extension show subcategory in the current category. If you like this you can download it here https://github.com/magepow/magento-2-categories
If you want get treeNode category you can code here https://github.com/magepow/magento-2-programmatically/blob/master/treeNode.php

Answer (score 0):

```
if($this->getLayer()->getCurrentCategory()):
$subcategories=$this->getLayer()->getCurrentCategory()->getCategories($this->getLayer()->getCurrentCategory()->getId());
    /* count and check the category have any sub category */
    if($subcategories->count()>0){

        foreach($subcategories as $subcategory){
            //echo "<pre>";
            //print_r($subcategory->getData());
            echo $subcategory->getName();
        }

    }else{
        // category does not have any sub category
    }
else:
        // category does not have any sub category

endif;
```